# Layout Grid with Buttons at the very bottom and ScrollView in the middle not showing Buttons

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI App, I use a Popup from the Community Toolkit and set its size in the parents OnSizeAllocated. Obviously the Size of the Popup itself seems to be okay for me.

Unfortunately, my Grid is not showing my Buttons on the very bottom anymore and I don't get it what I am do wrong here. On top, I have a SearchBar and at the bottom there should be my Buttons with Height "35". In the middle, I use a ScrollView with the CollectionView which should take the available space. With available space I mean it the top for the SearchBar and the Bottom for the Buttons with Height "35" are fixed and the rest in the middle can be used for the ScrollView/CollectionView

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, *, 35" Background="White" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

    <!-- SearchBar in the first row -->
    <SearchBar Grid.Row="0" ios:SearchBar.SearchBarStyle="Minimal" Text="{Binding SearchText}" Placeholder="Search" Margin="0, 0, 0, 5"  />


    <ScrollView Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">

        <CollectionView Background="Red" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedSavedItems, Mode=TwoWay}" IsGrouped="True" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSaved, Mode=TwoWay}">

            <!-- Group Header showing Headings for a Group and a box -->
            <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:GroupedSavedItemList">
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <Label FontSize="14" FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding GroupName, StringFormat=' {0}'}" TextColor="{StaticResource DarkOrange1}" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
                        <BoxView HeightRequest="0.5" Color="{StaticResource Gray200}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,5,0,5" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

            <!-- Items with Name, LastSavedDate ... -->
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type databaseModels:Saved}">

                    <SwipeView>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource LightOrange2}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <SwipeView.RightItems>
                            <SwipeItems>
                                <SwipeItem Text="Delete" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource DarkOrange1}"
                                           Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:CustomPopupViewModel}}, Path=DeleteSavedCommand}"
                                           CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                            </SwipeItems>
                        </SwipeView.RightItems>

                        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, Auto" Padding="5, 10">
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="14" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LastSavedDate, StringFormat='{}{0:d}'}" FontSize="14" />
                        </Grid>
                    </SwipeView>

                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </ScrollView>

    <!-- Cancel/OK-Button -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" ColumnDefinitions="Auto, Auto" ColumnSpacing="5" Margin="10" HorizontalOptions="End">

        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="FontAutoScalingEnabled" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="35" />
                <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="100" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15, 7, 15, 10" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Button Grid.Column="0" Text="{loc:Translate CancelButtonText}" Clicked="CancelButton_Clicked" />
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="{loc:Translate OKButtonText}" Clicked="OkButton_Clicked" Command="{Binding OkButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedSaved}" />

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Unfortunately, it just looks like this and I don't get it why my Buttons are not visible anymore. It is totally different from what I expected

[image]

For one reason, everything looks good until I add the code for the CollectionView

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, *, Auto" Background="White" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

    <!-- SearchBar in the first row -->
    <SearchBar Grid.Row="0" ios:SearchBar.SearchBarStyle="Minimal" Text="{Binding SearchText}" Placeholder="Search..." Margin="0, 0, 0, 5"  />

    <ScrollView Background="Red" Grid.Row="1">
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedSavedMealItems, Mode=TwoWay}" IsGrouped="True" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSaved, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalOptions="Fill">
        </CollectionView>
    </ScrollView>

    <!-- Cancel/OK-Button -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" ColumnDefinitions="Auto, Auto" ColumnSpacing="5" HeightRequest="35" Margin="15" HorizontalOptions="End">

        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="FontAutoScalingEnabled" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="35" />
                <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="100" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15, 7, 15, 10" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Button Grid.Column="0" Text="{loc:Translate CancelButtonText}" Clicked="CancelButton_Clicked" />
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="{loc:Translate OKButtonText}" Clicked="OkButton_Clicked" Command="{Binding OkButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedSavedMeal}" />

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

**Before adding the CollectionView**

[image]

So, actually what I wanted to achieve was that the ScrollView takes all the available space and scrolls the content of the ContentView when it expands. Here it looks like the ContentView expands my ScrollView what was not intended.

Is there a way, I can achieve that without setting a HeightRequest?

Comment: a `CollectionView` does not need to be contained in a `ScrollView`

Comment: First, I left it out and had the initial problem and thought the CollectionView increases that much that it goes out of the available scope. I thought it could help to put it in a ScrollView so that it scrolls in this case. I do not get it why it increases out if the available area even if the CollectionView does not have any content at the moment. Is there a good way to fill the middle area of the Grid without increasing it? If possible without setting a Height manually, which is not really good regarding different Mobile Phone sizes

Comment: @Jason - I do not have a better idea than I posted in my answer. If you have anything better in mind, please let me know

Comment: *"Is there a good way to fill the middle area of the Grid without increasing it?"* That is what is supposed to happen, given "Auto,*,Auto". Sounds like a Muai bug with CollectionView. Target Windows or Android or iOS? Regardless, take away the ScrollView.

Comment: This is what I did after comment of @Jason, but behavior is the same. I thought it was more or less a bug in my code - but other than doing it like above, I do not see possibilities right now :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I do not have a better idea than setting the Height of the Row in the middle for the CollectionView (Row=1) when the Size of the parent Grid was changed. The size is set with the Size of the parent Grid reduced by a Height of the SearchBar in Row=0 (plus Margin) and the Height of the Buttons in Row=2 (plus Margin).

So, I assume the first and last Row consume a Height of 125 in total. I've provided an x:Name for the parent Grid and implemented the Size_Changed-Event. In there, I set the Height of Row=1 which is reserved for the CollectionView in the Grid with RowDefinitios="*".

I would have calculated this based on the actual Height of the SearBar in Row=0 and the Buttons in Row=2, but in the Size_Changed-Event of the Parent Grid, I just get a value 1 from the ParentGrid.RowDefinitions[0].Height.Value and ParentGrid.RowDefinitions[2].Height.Value as they are probably not calculated at this time.

Please, if anybody has a better idea let me know and maybe mark your ideas as an answer:

```
<Grid x:Name="PopupParentGrid" RowDefinitions="Auto, *, Auto" Background="White" SizeChanged="Grid_SizeChanged">

    <!-- SearchBar in the first row -->
    <SearchBar Grid.Row="0" ios:SearchBar.SearchBarStyle="Minimal" Text="{Binding SearchText}" Placeholder="Search" Margin="0, 0, 0, 5"  />

    <CollectionView x:Name="PopupCollectionView" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedSavedItems, Mode=TwoWay}" IsGrouped="True" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSaved, Mode=TwoWay}" >
    </CollectionView>

    <!-- Cancel/OK-Button -->
    <Grid x:Name="PopupButtonBar" Grid.Row="2" ColumnDefinitions="Auto, Auto" ColumnSpacing="5" HeightRequest="35" Margin="15" HorizontalOptions="End">

        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="FontAutoScalingEnabled" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="35" />
                <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="100" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15, 7, 15, 10" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Button Grid.Column="0" Text="{loc:Translate CancelButtonText}" Clicked="CancelButton_Clicked" />
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="{loc:Translate OKButtonText}" Clicked="OkButton_Clicked" Command="{Binding OkButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedSavedMeal}" />

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
private void Grid_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PopupCollectionView.HeightRequest = PopupParentGrid.Height - 125;
}
```

Comment: My idea is a hack. If one of the heights is still 0, delay then try again: `if (... == 0) Dispatcher.Dispatch( async() => { await Task.Delay(200); PopupCollectionView.HeightRequest = ...; });` If still 0, give up and use a fixed size, as a fallback. Or keep looping, until not 0. After several tries, give up, use fixed size. Don't want to get stuck in loop. If you try this, add it to your answer.

Comment: The Heights were 1 which is strange - I thought this is a standard behavior when RowDefinitions are "Auto", but a delay could also help.

Comment: I guess "1" is a default sometimes. The heights do get corrected eventually...